# Как вынести код в метод? c#

Tags: c#, task

Есть код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace TimeTress
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "../../../../timeline.csv";

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                foreach (var timeline in lines)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(timeline);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Файл timeline.csv не найден по  пути {Path.GetFullPath(path)}");
            }

            string pathTwo = "../../../../people.csv";

            if (File.Exists(pathTwo))
            {
                string[] linesTwo = File.ReadAllLines(pathTwo);
                foreach (var people in linesTwo)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(people);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Файл people.csv не найден по пути {Path.GetFullPath(pathTwo)}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В нем два раза считываю строки, как можно вынести считывание строк с файла в метод.

Текст файлов:
timeline:
{дата_события};{описание_события}
people:
{Имя};{дата_рождения};{дата_смерти}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AwesomeMethod("Путь к файлу");
    }

    static void AwesomeMethod(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Файл не найден по пути {Path.GetFullPath(path)}");
        }
    }
```